# Cocoa - Bound Array is empty when trying to write

Tags: nsarray, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

I am writing a Master-Detail program in XCode, and want to add the ability to save all the data the user has put in. Currently I have an `assignmentArray` (`NSMutableArray`) in my controller object that is bound to an `NSArrayController`. When clicking a button, it should add an instance of my model object to the array. This appears to work fine. However, when I try to save it, the array is empty. As far as I have seen from debugging, the array is always empty. Why is it not containing these objects? 
I followed [this](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000084.php) tutorial and my code doesn't have any errors or warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I bound the ArrayController to the model object instead of File's Owner. Changing this fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have bound your ArrayController to `File's Owner` and not an instant of your controller!